# Log4net with SyslogAppender, 1kb message limit

Tags: log4net, syslog

Has anyone found a way to get around this? Or a better technique to conglomerate logging from multiple web servers reliably?

Any ideas on good log4net log file analysis tools too (plain text not XML) - apart from good 'ol grep of course :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1024 byte limit is part of the syslog [RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3164.txt) (section 4.1), as is UDP transport which doesn't have guaranteed delivery (in case you worry about log lines lost in the ether).  I think syslog-ng can solve both these issues, but I'm not a syslog expert.

Answer (score 2):

I read about [logFaces](http://www.moonlit-software.com/logfaces/web/index.php) on another question, or you could use a socket appender and write your own server. logFaces describes itself as a "Log server, aggregator & viewer" but I'm yet to try it.

Answer (score 1):

The database-based appenders are great for collecting logs from multiple servers.

Answer (score 0):

The limitation is imposed by the syslog itself, not the appender.

I do not know about log4net, but [NLog](http://www.nlog-project.org/) works perfectly ok with "shared" file target - i.e. multiple processes can write in one and the same [file](http://www.nlog-project.org/target.File.html).